# Verwendung der Präposition „zu“

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

Ich habe den nächsten Satz in einer Geschichte gelesen:

> Vielen Dank an *(jemanden)* für die wunderschöne Art zur (zu der) Geschichte.

Warum benutzt der Autor oder die Autorin „zu“? Was bedeutet das an dieser Stelle?

Ich habe viel recherchiert, aber ich kann keine gute Antwort finden (über die Verwendungen und Bedeutung dieser Wörter).

Comment: Ich habe es eingefügt. Danke! Ich werde das jetzt korrigieren. Es ist nur eine Note vor der Geschichte, um zu erkennen, was diese Person für den/die Autor(in) gemacht hat (diese Person hat ihn/sie eigene Bilder gesendet, und der/die Autor(in) hat sie am Anfang der Geschichte). Das ist sehr deutlich, wenn man die Geschichte beginnt zu lesen. Ich weiß, dass der/die Autor(in) das bedeutet, nur ich weiß nicht, warum er/sie "Art zur Geschichte" gesagt hat. RHa hat es doch erklärt. Ich weiß nicht doch warum "zur" statt "in" oder "an".

Comment: Statt offenzulassen, ob es eine Autorin oder ein männlicher Autor war, könntest Du auch sagen, wie Geschichte und Autor heißen und die Seitenzahl nennen. Wenn es kein ordentliches Zitat ist, sondern aus dem Gedächtnis paraphrasiert, erklärt dies auch die Fehler im Satz, die ein Erklären aber auch verunmöglichen. (Ihm/ihr eigene Bilder gesendet, müsste es im Kommentar heißen.) Bitte den Satz noch mal verifizieren und prüfen, was darin wirklich steht.

Answer (score 2):

"Art" klingt hier wie ein Übersetzungsfehler. Waren vielleicht *Kunstwerke* gemeint?

> Vielen Dank an (Max Mustermann) für die wunderschönen Bilder zur Geschichte.

Gleichbedeutend mit

> Vielen Dank an (Max Mustermann) für die wunderschöne Bebilderung der Geschichte.

Answer (score 0):

Man kann das deutsche Substantiv *die Art* nicht so wie in deinem Beispiel benutzen, auch nicht das deutsche Substantiv *die Kunst*. Es klappt allerdings z.B. mit den Substantiven *die Erzählung*, *die Sage*, *die Erläuterung* usw.:

> Vielen Dank an … für die wunderschöne Erzählung zur Geschichte (dieser Burg).

Dieser Satz ist fast gleichwertig zu folgendem Satz:

> Vielen Dank an … für die wunderschöne Erzählung der Geschichte (dieser Burg).

Der Unterschied ist, dass der Satz mit "zu" die Erzählung als nicht unbedingt vollständig oder zutreffend beschreibt — vielleicht wurde auch nur eine Sage erzählt —, während der Satz mit "der" erklärt, dass alles Wesentliche über die Geschichte (der Burg) gesagt wurde. "Zu" meint "dazu". Eine Zugabe.

Comment: Es würde auch Sinn ergeben, wenn man *Geschichte* als Erzählung o.Ä. versteht und *Art* durch Illustration ersetzt: Vielen Dank an N.N. die wunderschöne Illustration zur Geschichte. So wie er da steht ergibt der Satz in der Tat keinen Sinn und weckt den Verdacht, dass er das Produkt maschineller Übersetzung sein könnte.

Comment: Das war, was ich dachte, denn es gibt viele Bilder am Anfang der Geschichte. Wie ich gesagt habe, habe ich diese Bedeutung von "Art" nirgendwo gefunden (dass "Art" diese änhliche Bedeutung hatte, wie auf Englisch). Es macht ja total Sinn, was du sagst! Danke sehr! Ich würde doch wissen, warum nicht "in/an der Geschichte"?

Comment: Man kann die Frage *warum* eine bestimmte Präposition verwendet wird und nicht etwa eine andere, in den meisten Fällen nicht beantworten.

Comment: @David F. Die 'Geschichte' ist einerseits der erzählte Inhalt, das, was sich im Kopf des Lesers beim Lesen abspielt. Illustrationen liefern **zu** ihr eine eigene Interpretation. Andererseits "ist" die Geschichte auch: ein Buch, viele Seiten Papier, die Buchstaben auf dieser Seite, kurz: ein materieller Text. Illustrationen sind **in** den Text der Geschichte eingebettet. **An** der Geschichte würde grob gesagt bedeuten: An dem Text hängen oder kleben (?) noch irgendwelche Zeichnungen, da wäre **bei** passender, aber auch nicht gut. In der konkreten Realität sind 'erzählter Inhalt' und ...

Comment: @David F. (Fortsetzung) ... Buch/Text aneinander gebunden. Aus der Leserperspektive sind Illustrationen etwas der erzählten Geschichte Hin**zu**gefügtes, ein **zu**sätzlicher Inhalt. Auch aus der Verlegerperspektive (der Perspektive des Buchproduzenten) sind Illustrationen ein finanzieller und produktionstechnischer Mehraufwand, und sie müssen auch **zu** dem Inhalt passen. Auch solange Text und Illustrationen noch nicht veröffentlicht sind, sind Zeichnungen ein Mehr, sie kommen hin**zu**, verbrauchen Papier, 'Lesezeit', sind nicht Teil des Erzählten, außer bei Comics oder   Comicartigem.